# Testing retina.js without retina display?

Tags: resolution, javascript, macbook-pro-retina

I'd like to test [retina.js](http://retinajs.com/), but I don't have a retina display, and without going to Best Buy (and staring at the pixels for 10 minutes), I don't have access to one. Since I have a standard display, I can't simply zoom in and see the difference (even if the high res image is loaded, it's still rendered with large pixels). Is there any other way to tell if the retina graphics are being served?

Comment: Does retina.js obfuscate image URLs? Can't you check which image version has been served to you by looking at its URL/name? (See if it has **@2x** appended to it.)

Comment: @Karan but I don't have a retina display, it serves the regular image.

Comment: As per a quick read, retina.js will serve *Xyz.jpg* to you if you lack a retina display, and *Xyz@2x.jpg* if you have one. Why not simply ensure that *Xyz.jpg* is a retina capable image itself? During retina testing make *all* copies of the images on your test site use the retina versions, and that way you can ensure that what you're seeing are the high-res images.

Comment: You can enable HiDPI mode even if you don't have a retina display: http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20110805141544753  I think you do need a relatively high resolution display to enable this though.

Comment: @Szabolcs I've only got 1280x800. I plan on getting a retina macbook pro in a few months, I guess I can just wait until then.

Comment: @tkbx That site says that then you should be able to enable a 640 by 400 HiDPI mode, but I haven't tried this personally.  I just thought you might find this info helpful as I was reading about it the other day.

Comment: You could simply artificial, easily identifiable `@2x` resources, like watermarked with a *2x* across the image, or a different image altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Get [Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/) from the Mac App Store and use the iOS simulators.

Comment: Could you perhaps expand your answer a little to address how this solves the problem? Do you mean the iOS simulators? Maybe you could include a screenshot or so?